# CodingForFun Toolkit Closing popup clears content from textboxes WP8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, nokia

I am using CodingForFun Toolkit to create a pop up on on Windows phone app page (xaml).

I used the following code example http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Create_simple_overlay_with_UserControl_in_Windows_Phone#?ticket=ST-0e471fde-6d16-4345-8eaf-038344e8f195-a00475e0-92ab-4a0b-9a4e-dccb8fffb737.

My page contains textboxes as I am trying to create a form page that has a link at the bottom (accept terms and conditions) that opens using a popup. But when I close the Popup using the back key on the phone the form content is cleared.

How can I keep the content even after closing the popup?

Thanks

Comment: It is better to include your code in the question. Have you used exact same code in the sample? Have you handled the back key press correctly?

Comment: Yes. Its the exact same code except that I got some textboxes on my page.

Comment: where is your textboxes ? In user control ? or in the page?

Comment: in the page. The page also has a button which opens the popup over the same page.

Comment: Are you navigating back from the current when you close the popup ? Or staying in the page where you button resides?

Comment: It is the same page from where the pop up openened.

Comment: There is no way to lose data when you close popup from a page and stay on the same page unless you explicitly clear the data.

Comment: The back button clears the data i have in the textboxes.

Comment: Paste your code first